# mysql_fetch_array() returns 'supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource'

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying the following code:

```
<?php

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'geheim');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';



    $query = "SELECT * FROM Auctions";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        foreach($row as $field=>$value)
        {
            echo "$field: {$value} <br />";
        }
    }
    mysql_close($link);

?>
```

And get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a
    valid MySQL result resource in
    C:\Programme\EasyPHP 2.0b1\www\test.php on line 14
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't selected a database - use [`mysql_select_db()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_select_db)

That would be something like:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'geheim');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Error selecting database: '. mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Using database successfully';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Auctions";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        foreach($row as $field=>$value) {
            echo "$field: {$value} <br />";
        }
    }
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your MySQL query possibly does not match any rows in the database.

Check the return value of [mysql_query()](http://nl2.php.net/mysql_query), which returns "resource" on success and "false" on failure.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Auctions"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result !== false) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
        foreach ($row as $field=>$value) { 
            echo $field . ':' . $value
        }
    }
} else {
    // query returned 0 rows
}
```

As others also suggested, you can use [mysql_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to look if the query returns any mySQL errors

Comment: mysql_query only returns false on an actual error. An empty result set is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

$query = "SELECT * FROM Auctions";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

so you'll see the error

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting anything returned?  If no results are found, mysql_query returns FALSE.

Check that before running fetch_array.

Comment: If no results are found, it still returns a resource, but there are no results in it. `mysql_query()` only returns false if there is an error.