# SQL Nearest Date

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get a date such as '2010-04-27' as a string in php and find the nearest 5 dates in a table. The date in the table are saved as a date type.

Comment: This massive SQL, rubbish, and "SELECT * FROM times WHERE date <= date('.$date.') LIMIT 0,3 ORDER BY date ASC"

Answer (score 3):

you can use  [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)   + [ABS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs)

```
SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(myfield,'2010-04-27')) AS diff FROM mytable ORDER BY diff LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Im getting 'is not a valid resource'

Comment: check this for "is not a valid resource":
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253378/not-a-valid-mysql-resource

Comment: This doesnt appear to be filling $row.
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
The array row contains no column data

Answer (score 2):

you could also query the difference eg. something like

abs(datediff(date, $date))

then order by this